# Getting the indexes of NSButtons in an array and appending them to an array of integers in swift (Cocoa)

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa

I'm super new to programming so this may be a pretty basic question.

I have an array of NSButtons (checkboxes) in my ViewController that I am calling "buttonArray." I want to go through the array, find out which buttons are checked and add the indexes of those checked buttons to another array of integers (located in a struct), which I am calling "intArray." This is the struct:

```
struct GetInterval {
    var intArray = [Int]()
    mutating func putIntIntoArray (intToAdd:Int) {
        self.intArray.append(intToAdd)
    }
}
```

I have tried doing this two ways (shown below), both of which have given me compiler errors.

First, I tried to use a function to import the index as an Int and add it to the "intArray" array...

```
for interval in buttonArray {
    if interval.state == NSOnState {
        var intervalIndex = find(buttonArray, interval)
        GetInterval.putIntIntoArray(Int(intervalIndex!))
    }
}
```

...which gave me the error: "**Cannot invoke 'putIntoArray' with argument list of type ((int))**"

When that didn't work, I tried appending it directly from the "if" statement in the ViewController...

```
for interval in buttonArray {
    if interval.state == NSOnState {
        var intervalIndex = find(buttonArray, interval)
        GetInterval.intArray.append(intervalIndex!)
    }
}
```

...which gives me the error: "**GetInterval.Type does not have a member named 'intArray'**"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `GetInterval.(something)`, this refers to a **static member** (a.k.a., something owned by the GetInterval type). However, your `intArray` is a member owned by **each instance** of the GetInterval type. So you need to create an instance first. For example:

```
var getInt = GetInterval() // create a new instance

getInt.putIntIntoArray(...) // modify this instance, by calling a mutating function
getInt.intArray.append(...) // modify this instance, by directly accessing a property
```